# Interactive lualatex compiling

Tags: luatex

I have a made document using `LuaLaTeX` with some constants I have to change each time regarding about the circumstances.

Is there a way that `LuaLaTeX` open an interactive window to ask me the value for the constants?

For example, I want to be ask for `n` in the next  `MWE`:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{luacode}

\newcommand{\bob}{%
    \luadirect{
    n = 5
    for i = 1,n
    do
        tex.print(i)
    end
    }
}

\begin{document}

\bob

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have a rather primitive form of interaction if you run LuaLaTeX in interactive mode to begin with, that is, from a shell (a console/terminal, in other words). All front ends run LaTeX (any engine) in non interactive mode.

Here's how:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{luacode}

\typein[\myn]{Tell me n, boss!}

\newcommand{\bob}{%
    \luadirect{
    n = \myn\space
    for i = 1,n
    do
        tex.print(i)
    end
    }
}

\begin{document}

\bob

\end{document}
```

The run on the terminal will interrupt with the message

```
Tell me n, boss!

\myn =
```

to which you should answer by typing a number.

No window system, I'm afraid. You can get a window with a fancy dialog box with any scripting language; the answer should be used to make the script run something like

```
lualatex -interaction=nonstopmode '\def\myn{<the answer>}\input{<filename>}'
```

(add all other options you need). The `\typein` line should not be used, in this case.